# Python- if statement evaluation pattern

Tags: python

what the heck is the if statement doing?

```
>>> list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> for i in xrange(len(list)):
...   if i / 2:
...     del(list[0])
```

and this will result in ['e', 'f']

I dont know that the if is doing.

Comment: Evaluating `if i/2` so for the range `0,1,2,3,4,5` you get `0,0,1,1,2,2`, which evaluates to `F,F,T,T,T,T`. Given `4` `True`s it deletes the front 4 items... hence `['e', 'f']`. While legitimate code it is basically meaningless.

Comment: what do u wish to achieve ?

Comment: @AChampion is completely right; also note whatever you're trying to do; this is definitely the wrong way. Modifying a list while iterating can lead to counter intuitive outcomes and`del`eting an item from the start of a list if O(n)

Comment: Also don't use variable names that hide Python builtins, e.g. `list`.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically saying:

> *Remove the first element of the list (`del(list[0])`) **while** `i` divided by `2` is greater than zero (`i/2`)*

Since it's not true in the first two cycles, you're left with the last two elements. Because `0/2` and `1/2` returns `0` since they're integers.

Answer (score 0):

Python interprets `i/2` as a boolean expression: if it equals `0` the the expression ist considered false, else it is considered true. Let's look at the code line by line:

---

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

We create a list with those 6 elements

```
for i in xrange(len(list)):
```

`len(list)` is the length of our list, i.e. 6 and `xrange(n)` allows you to iterate an integer from `0` to `n-1` (at each loop, `i` will be `0`, `1`, ..., `6`)

```
    if i / 2:
```

We check if the integer division from `i` by `2` is true or false. Remember: `0` is equivalent to `False`, everything else to `True`.

When `i` is `0` or `1`, the quotient `i/2` is 0, therefore the next statement is not executed. in the 4 other cases (`i` is `2`, `3`, `4` , `5`), `i/2` is greater than `0`. There fore we execute the statement.

```
        del(lst[0])
```

This simply asks to delete the first element of the list, and we've seen that this will be done 4 times, hence the result is a list with just the two last elements remaining.

---

The process can be visualized as follows (remember that `/` is the euclidian division in Python):

```
BEGIN OF LOOP
i=0, lst=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
  i/2 = 0/2 = 0 --> False --> Nothing happens
i=1, lst=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
  i/2 = 1/2 = 0 --> False --> Nothing happens
i=2, lst=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
  i/2 = 2/2 = 1 --> True --> Remove first element ('a')
i=3, lst=['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
  i/2 = 3/2 = 1 --> True --> Remove first element ('b')
i=4, lst=['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
  i/2 = 4/2 = 2 --> True --> Remove first element ('c')
i=5, lst=['d', 'e', 'f']
  i/2 = 5/2 = 2 --> True --> Remove first element ('d')
END OF LOOP

lst=['e', 'f']
```

Comment: what does euclidian division mean? Is it  different from normal division?

Comment: It's just the name for division with quotient and rest ;) 9/4 is 2, rest is 1 because 9=4*2+1. You may know this as integer division

Answer (score 0):

If 'i' is equals to, or bigger than 2, it deletes the first element of the list. 0 is equivalent to false, and 1 or more, is equivalent to true.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this to know for each iteration what happens with your list.

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
for i in xrange(len(list)):
    print (i)
    print list
    if (i / 2):
        del(list[0])

print list
```

for 1st,2nd iteration when `i=0` or `i=1` then statement `if i/2:` evaluates to `zero` i.e `False` hence code under `if` statement does not executes.

for Further iterations from `i=2` to `i=5` then statement `if i/2:` evaluates to some `value` i.e. considered `True` hence code under `if` statement executes and deletes the first element of `list`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

the if statement is deleting elements in you list at indices greater than  or equal to 2.

`if i/2:` will evaluate to true when i/2 is not 0. i.e. index>=2.